# Kafka CooperativeStickyAssignor assigns all partitions to 1 consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

setup:

- kafka 2.8 (server) and java org.apache.kafka kafka-clients version: 3.0.0
- 4 pods on kubernetes running kafka consumers
- consumer properties: max poll interval of 5 minutes, session of 45 seconds
- all consumers "subscribe" to the same topic, using a consumer group.id
- Setting partition.assignment.strategy to CooperativeStickyAssignor
- 1024 partitions

**Issues**

I'm monitoring which partitions get assigned to which consumer/pod and I see some big issues when I play with the number of pods (deleting/recreating 1 pod or all pods at the same time)

- For 5 minutes in a row, it happens sometimes that not all partitions get assigned, and then they are all assigned and well balanced. I don't understand why the rebalance doesn't happen earlier since the session length is 45 seconds
- sometimes ALL partitions get assigned to 1 consumer. Looking at logs it says that partitions get assigned to consumer 1 and consumer 2 (and nothing "revoked"), but really when testing all partitions are consumed by only 1 consumer

Any idea what can be wrong about the configuration? I'm trying to keep it as close possible to the default. Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: I have seen the same issue with CooperativeStickyAssignor. Works for weeks and then at a rebalance all partitions get assigned to one consumer. On the client side (spring cloud stream) the client thinks it has partitions but at offset commit time the broker rejects, triggering a rebalance again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is related to this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-14639